# react optimize performance by reducing API calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Says u have an userProfile container, they have userList and userDetail. The expected behavior would be when the user click on an item on the list, it shows the detail of a user.

There's a problem here, it requires 2 calls, one call to get the userList and another call to get the userDetail. But the API of userList contain everything that's need for their profile.

How to avoid call the userDetail? unlike angularjs, I can't pass object through `Link`. I'm not using redux.

Comment: Are you using React Router?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja yes

Comment: Can you post your Router configuration here?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja https://pastebin.com/raw/569nQ1Na

Comment: So how do you want to populate the data to your components, I can't see two components for `userList` and `userDetails` ? You have only one component `AdminDashboardProfileDetail` does this have both ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you actually using the full power of ReactJS.
ReactJS is a SPA, where reloads doesn't require. Sure you using React Router and you probably don't. But if you fetch the `userList` which is contains all the information, you need to store it somewhere. You know, to cache it.
So in a normal application you will show a loader to fetch the `userList` then cache it, this is why we have [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) and [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux). (and more, or just handle it yourself.)

The solution to have 1 call for all the users is simple, when you listen to each user item click and then request depending on the user id is useless since like you said you already have all the information you need.

Your change isn't big, just simply store the `userList` once you receive it and in the each user item click instead of fetching it from the server just pull it out of the array you saved.
This may require few changes you probably don't have already in your base code.

My advice to you since its looks like you new to this, since you missing some things. Just read about it more, look at ReactJS Starter kits and blogs.
Personally I would have cache the `userList` even in isomorphic application.